# How can i combine the reduce and forEach

Tags: javascript, arrays

How can I combine this reduce and forEach so that we only traverse the list one time.

```js
obj.arr = (obj.arr || []).reduce((newArr, arr2) => {
  if (arr2.name !== anyProperty) {
    newArr.push(arr2);
  }
  return newArr;
}, []);

obj.arr.forEach((arr2) => {
  obj.arr[arr2.name] = arr2;
});
```

Comment: please add your real/actual code and an example of input and expected output

Comment: I think the code is understandable, thats why i wrote like object and array. Only thing is we are using reduce and then forEach so here we are traversing the list 2 times, thats why we want to combine reduce and forEach and the above logic should fit into that.

Comment: Please give an example array that this code would run on. That would help everyone. `obj.arr = []` -- what do the objects look like in this array? what is `anyProperty`? The example isn't full

Comment: As per your example, it's not possible to guess and avoid a traversal unless you provide some data and so that we know what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Really, the first call should've been a `filter` and the second should've been a `reduce`.

Comment: obj.arr = (obj.arr || []).reduce((newArr, arr2) => {
    if (arr2.name !== anyProperty) {
        newArr.push(arr2);
        newArr[arr2.name] = arr2;
 }

    return newArr;
});

I tried this but it is saying newArr.push is not a function.

Comment: @AnkitaSharma You've missed to supply `[]` as the initial value in that `reduce` call

Comment: Btw, [don't abuse arrays by putting named properties on them](https://andrewdupont.net/2006/05/18/javascript-associative-arrays-considered-harmful/)

Comment: simple example of input:
obj = {
    arr: [a, b, c]
};

Comment: Oh! ya that helped Bergi Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Check this code:

```js
let anyProperty = 'test';
let obj = {
  arr: [
    { name: 'a', value: 1 },
    { name: 'test', value: 2 },
    { name: 'b', value: 3 },
  ]
};

obj.arr = Object.fromEntries((obj.arr || [])
  .filter(item => item.name !== anyProperty)
  .map(item => [item.name, item]));

console.log(obj.arr);
```